# How can I combine repeating rows only returning a single instance of repeating data?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  | Time  | Metadata
======================
1   | 01:00 | Foo
2   | 02:00 | Foo
3   | 03:00 | Foo
4   | 04:00 | Bar
5   | 05:00 | Bar
6   | 06:00 | Bar
7   | 07:00 | Foo
8   | 08:00 | Foo
9   | 09:00 | Foo
10  | 10:00 | Foo
11  | 11:00 | Foo
12  | 12:00 | Foo
```

I'd like to get the all the first instances of metadata changing, like this:

```
ID  | Time  | Metadata
======================
1   | 01:00 | Foo
4   | 04:00 | Bar
7   | 07:00 | Foo
```

`GROUP BY` would group rows 1 and 7 together, which isn't what I want. I could do it outside of SQL, but that will require rather large selections of data which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476761/mysql-group-by-consecutive-appearances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more approach

```
SELECT id, `time`, metadata
FROM 
(select @cnt := 0, @previous := '' from dual) dummy
join (

  SELECT  id, `time`,
      metadata, @cnt := IF(metadata = @previous, @cnt + 1, 1) occurence,
      @previous := metadata FROM trytable

) a where occurence = 1;
```

[Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8a5b/14/0)

Comment: I agree, performance should be better in your solution. I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be to create a stored procedure and perform the "metadata change" logic inside it. The stored procedure would return a cursor to the set you need. 
This way you don't fetch a huge amount of data to a client and do the processing on the client.

Comment: I wanted to do this, but I'd have to compare the previous meta data with new. I simplified the example in the OP, but a new row is added once a minute for servers we're tracking and there's almost 2k of them. Selecting the data needed to compare each insertion was too time expensive, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t11.*
from test1 t11
where 
t11.metadata <> (select t12.metadata from test1 t12
                 where t11.id > t12.id
                 order by t12.id desc
                 limit 1
                )
or not exists (select 1 from test1 t13
               where t11.id > t13.id)
order by id
```

Demo [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3df88/20)